# How to find cause of reset in PIC16F microcontroller?

Tags: pic, microchip, reset

I've worked with other microcontrollers that have a register that I can check on powerup to check a register that contains debugging information on the cause of the reset.

Initial searching revealed an RCON register that may not be available in my current PIC.  Haven't found much in the initial search of the datasheet either:

http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC16F1704

Comment: related: [Reporting crashes/resets in Embedded Systems (8 bit)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/98002/7036)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the PCON register in the datasheet (took some searching).  See page 61 of the linked datasheet:

- Brown-out Reset (BOR)
- Reset Instruction Reset (RI)
- MCLR Reset (RMCLR)
- Watchdog Timer Reset (RWDT)
- Stack Underflow Reset (STKUNF)
- Stack Overflow Reset (STKOVF)

Haven't heard of a stack underflow error.  Searching the meaning of that now...

Comment: A stack underflow error is just the opposite of a stack overflow error.  Instead of pushing too many bytes onto the stack and running out of room (stack overflow), a stack underflow occurs when you have popped all of the legitimate stack and are sitting at the top (original starting point), and then try to do another pop.